# Помогите плиз сбросить итератор в листе

Tags: java, циклы, итераторы

Суть такова. Я хочу написать методы, при вызове которого будет возвращаться элемент листа. А после последнего элемента вернется первый, потом второй. То есть цикл и в обратном направлении. С методом next() вроде все понятно. А вот с prev() уже сложнее. В метод prev()  итератор приходить на нулевом элементе. Я его пытаюсь поставить на последний. Но он не совсем корректно работает. Вот что мне надо. В конструктор передаю следующие параметры  CircularList cl = new CircularList("one", "two", "three");

затем вызываю метод next() к примеру четыре раза. последнее значение, которое вернет итератор будет "one"
далее я буду вызывать метод prev() и он начнет со значения  "one", а я хочу чтобы он вернул предыдущее значение, которое будет равно  "three".

вот что я смог накодить.

```
    T next() {

    while (true) {
        if (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            return listIterator.next();
        } else {
            listIterator = list.listIterator();
        }
    }
}

T prev() {
    if (!listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            listIterator.next();
        }
    }
    while (true) {
        if (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            return listIterator.previous();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [List.listIterator(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator(int)) устанавливает итератор на указанную позицию. В случае метода `previous` его следует установить после последнего элемента списка.

Если поправить остальные ошибки, то в вашей нотации методы могут выглядеть так:

```
    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (!listIterator.hasNext()) {
            listIterator = list.listIterator();
        }
        return listIterator.next();
    }

    @Override
    public T previous() {
        if (!listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            listIterator = list.listIterator(list.size());
        }
        return listIterator.previous();
    }
```

**P.S.** Требование не повторять элемент при смене направления итерации тоже можно реализовать. Задача решается в два шага: `CircularListIterator` - реализует стандартную логику (значения повторяются), `CustomCircularListIterator` не повторяет значения.

Для краткости этот код не реализует интерфейс `java.util.ListIterator`, возвращаясь к оригинальной нотации:

```
public class CircularListIterator<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    private ListIterator<T> listIterator;

    public CircularListIterator(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
        listIterator = list.listIterator();
    }

    public T next() {
        if (!listIterator.hasNext()) {
            listIterator = list.listIterator();
        }
        return listIterator.next();
    }

    public T prev() {
        if (!listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            listIterator = list.listIterator(list.size());
        }
        return listIterator.previous();
    }
}

public class CustomCircularListIterator<T> {
    private CircularListIterator<T> listIterator;
    private boolean up;

    public CustomCircularListIterator(List<T> list) {
        listIterator = new CircularListIterator<T>(list);
        up = true;
    }

    public T next() {
        if (!up) {
            listIterator.next();
            up = true;
        }
        return listIterator.next();
    }

    public T prev() {
        if (up) {
            listIterator.prev();
            up = false;
        }
        return listIterator.prev();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Код стал более компактным. Но вот вопрос. Допустим у нас три элемента int 1, 2 ,3. И метод prev() возвращает значение , равное значению, которое вернул метод next() последним. Если next вернет три то и prev вернет 3. И еще вот вопрос. Почему мы можем писать   listIterator = list.listIterator(list.size()); ? ведь если у нас три элемента то этот индекс находится за пределами list

Comment: `previous` после `next` возвращает тот-же элемент. Это поведение выполняется для стандартного `ListIterator`. Оно же воспроизведено для циклического.

Comment: `list.listIterator(list.size())` разрешено в документации.

Comment: Код, который вы видите, протестирован.

Comment: Так что же делать. Мне не надо дублировать элемент. Придется делать override методов ListIteratora и писать в них свою логику чи шо?

Comment: Дублировать или нет - решайте сами, я про другое. Если в списке `(1, 2, 3)` вы три раза вызовите `next` то вы получите `1, 2, 3`. Если затем вы три раза вызовете `previous` то получите `3, 2, 1`. Логично?

Comment: Возможно я не понял что вам нужно. Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос конкретные примеры как должен работать итератор.

Comment: мне нужно стандартное поведение listIterator, только чтобы после метода next метод prev не повторял значение

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое